# Windows Phone 7 Listbox not displaying

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

So I have a listbox I am trying to make for an "achievement page". Everything works good if I use a List but when I switch it to a List there is nothing displayed, not even from the xaml...

```
public partial class achievementPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public achievementPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        loadListbox();
    }
    public achievementPage(string achievementGet, string d1)
    {  
    }
    public void loadListbox()
    {
        achievementStoreage.loadData();
        List<achievementPage> achievementList = new List<achievementPage>();
        achievementList.Add(new achievementPage(achievementStoreage.achievement1, "This is a        test"));
        achievementList.Add(new achievementPage(achievementStoreage.achievement2, "This is    another test")); 
        //List<string> achievementList = new List<string>();
        //achievementList.Add("Sup");
        achievementListBox.ItemsSource = achievementList;
    }
}

<ListBox Name="achievementListBox" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Width="776" Height="120" BorderBrush="Black">
                <Button.Content>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="50">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="40">
                            <TextBlock Width="150" Foreground="Black" FontSize="22" Text="Description:" Height="40"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

All I get is a blank page.. P.S don't worry about achievementStoreage, it is working properly.(just where I get stored data)

Comment: Where you are doing data binding with the listbox. ??

Comment: he is doing it here: `achievementListBox.ItemsSource = achievementList;` in the function `loadListBox` called in ctor..

Comment: But I was telling about binding with textblock Text property like this Text="{Binding AchvCount}"

Comment: True, he is missing that. But the list items would display anyways if other things were OK. Now the author sees a blank page, so not even the  text "description" is visible. Heh, now I've noticed the Foregroung=Black. Maybe just black text on default black background of the page? :) Whatever the case was, the list items really should not be a type of "achievementPage"...

Comment: Hey yeah, I removed the data binding just so I could get things working. Also "achievementPage" is not what you think lol, poor naming on my part I guess, it's just a class. Also I changed the background to white so I know nothing is hiding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, it seems that you are simply not allowed to use ItemTemplates along with UIElements as the items' DataContexts. I've tried with:

```
achievementListBox.ItemsSource = new [] {"a","b"};
```

and both items were visible and printed dummy "description" texts, but none of the following lines I've tried has presented anything at all:

```
achievementListBox.ItemsSource = new [] { new TextBlock(), new TextBlock()};
achievementListBox.ItemsSource = new [] { new Rectangle(), new Rectangle()};
achievementListBox.ItemsSource = new [] { new Grid(), new Grid()};
```

Trying with your custom page - the same. No items shown.

This is very misleading. The items **were** shown, but look at the lines above: the controls were created **empty**, with no contents set!.

It turns out, that if the ListBox detects that the Item is an UIElement, then it **does not** use the ItemTemplate, but it presents that UIElement directly!

```
achievementListBox.ItemsSource = new[] { new TextBlock() { Text = "bbb" }, new TextBlock() { Text = "eee" } };
achievementListBox.ItemsSource = new[] { new Rectangle() { Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), Width = 30, Height = 10 }, new Rectangle() { Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green), Width = 30, Height = 10 } };

var gridA = new Grid() { Width = 110, Height = 40 }; gridA.Children.Add(new Rectangle() { Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) });
var gridB = new Grid() { Width = 110, Height = 40 }; gridB.Children.Add(new Rectangle() { Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green) });
achievementListBox.ItemsSource = new[] { gridA, gridB };
```

All of the three above examples completely ignore the ListBox.ItemTemplate, and instead, they display two items directly:  two textboxes, two rectangles, two larger rectangles (in a Grid).

Getting back to your case: It means that with your original setup, the ListBox would try to display the items directly too - as your custom Page is a UIElement. And indeed it did that! But your pages were ... empty. In the overloaded constructor you omitted the `InitializeComponent();` that constructs the View by reading the XAML code. Here is a corrected example that displays a "Hello" three times: Once just because it lies on the page, and next two times because the ListBox rows are set to the same page.

Please excuse me for renaming the classes, I simply started a new project instead of pasting your code.
Please note that I had to add to the XAML some other controls, because the Pages used as the data items would be display as empty, because they would have no items set

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        loadListbox();
    }

    public MainPage(string achievementGet, string d1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        someText.Text = d1;
    }

    public void loadListbox()
    {
        achievementListBox.ItemsSource = new[] { new MainPage(null, "ddd"), new MainPage(null, "ccc") };
    }
}

<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock>
        <Run Text="Hello" />
        <Run Text=" " />
        <Run x:Name="someText" />
    </TextBlock>

    <ListBox Name="achievementListBox" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Width="150" Foreground="White"
                           FontSize="22" Text="This DataTemplate is IGNORED because the Item is UIElement"
                           Height="40"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

I tried to shape the code in a similar manner to yours, just removed some lines not relevant to the problem. I hope this explains you everything now :)

Answer (score 1):

Oh my. Why do create a list of `achievementPage`s? On your achievementPage you will want to have a `ListBox` with items of type, like, `AchievementItem`, `CompletedAchievement`, `NotCompletedAchievement`, etc.

Currently, nothing shows up because your code probably throws StackoverflowException (not joking here:)). Look: your achievementPage constructor calls loadListBox that creates two achievementPages and adds them to the list. But creating two achievementPages causes again their constructors to be called two times, which invokes loadListBox two times, and so on..

-- edit: ok, no stackoverflow, I've just noticed the second constructor. You should stick to naming the classes with capital letters you know :) Anyways, putting a `Page` as a data item of a `ListBox` on a `Page` is a **bad idea**.

What you wanted to get should look more like:

```
public partial class AchievementPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public AchievementPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        loadListbox();
    }

    public void loadListbox()
    {
        var theList = new List<Achievement>();
        theList.Add(new Achievement{ AchvCount=3, AchvName="medals" });
        theList.Add(new Achievement{ AchvCount=2, AchvName="badges"  }); 
        theList.Add(new Achievement{ AchvCount=6, AchvName="zonks"  }); 

        achievementListBox.ItemsSource = achievementList;
    }
}

public class Achievement : DependencyObject
{
    public int AchvCount {get; set;}
    public string AchvName {get; set;}
}

<ListBox Name="achievementListBox" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="You've got:" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding AchvCount}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding AchvName}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I've made the Achievement a "DependencyObject" but I've ommited the DependencyProperties for readability. If you want to have proper change notifications and UI autoupdates when the properties change - you will have to add them!

Comment: Good suggestion but I was looking for an answer as to why my code currently does not work, rather than making it work another way. Re-writing the code for me does not help me understand why my current code does not work. Again, the input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I understand, but I'm not having a WP7 device at hand to test your code, so I just "analyze in memory".. Seeing that second constructor overload, I do not see any errors. Attempt to use achievemntPage/PhoneApplicationPage as the list's data item is smelly, but it **should** work properly, just like you have tried in the lines below with a list of strings. The only thing I can imagine is the colour, but you say the bkg is white - so that's not it. I assume the XAML is complete and you are not adding / modifying the .ItemsSource or .Items props on the ListBox.. I'll try on the device on monday.

Comment: So, I ran it on the emu, indeed nothing showed up. When I changed the code to `achievementListBox.ItemsSource = new [] {"a","b"};` both items were visible.